# Run a bash command from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, bash, command-line

I have a bash command which I need to run in vb.net.

The command is like that:

```
for i in `seq 0 2` & ";" & "do ./abc.sh ""xyz -d $i" """" ";" & "done"
```

I tried multiple ways, using `Shell(command)` and

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(exePath)
Dim cmdSession As New Process

psi.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory
psi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
psi.UseShellExecute = True
psi.Arguments = "ls"
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
cmdSession.StartInfo = psi
cmdSession.Start()
```

but no success. Can anyone help me in executing these commands from bash shell. Tried searching other threads but no help.

Comment: With both VB.Net and VBScript in play, it sure looks like you're running this on Windows? Does the machine even have bash available? Windows has _batch_ scripting, and only rarely has _bash_ available at all. The two are very different.

Comment: Yes, the bash is available and I am running on Windows.

Comment: **How** is bash available? Are you using WSL? Because `cmd.exe` does **NOT** do bash natively. Whether you're using cygwin, WSL, or something else, will dictate the answer to this problem. Also, the calling environment will matter. How is the VB code here going to run?

Comment: Bash.exe is present at C:\Cygwin\bin. Vb code is calling through an automation tool.

Comment: Apart from whether Bash is available or not, that command looks strange... what's with the stray `&` everywhere?

Comment: This is in vb.net to concatenate two strings. you can ignore all "&" as the final command does not has "&".This is just for concatenating two strings.

Comment: The command is like "for i in `seq 0 2`;do ./abc.sh "xyz -d $i ";done"

Comment: Got it. So the first part of the script sent to `cmd.exe` needs to be starting the bash interpreter. Just because bash.exe is available on the system doesn't mean it's active right now.